# What's the point of using XML for Fragments?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

As I'm learning about Fragments and Android coding in general, I was wondering why the official documentation suggests using XML for Fragments in the first place? When you know for a fact that your Fragment won't be removed or modified at runtime, XML is fine. However, what's the point of getting into that practice if, and I'm quoting the [Intro to Fragments Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) here:

> "To create a dynamic and multi-pane user interface on Android"

What is the point of ever using XML over building one programatically? Should I spend time learning a static way to build a component that's meant to make your app more dynamic?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the same reason you would use XML with Activities. Fragments are somewhat like nested Activities and they enable you to break your UI into several independent components (which may or may not interact with each other). Each fragment manages its own layout. Prefer to use XML over dynamically creating your Views whenever possible, both with Activities and with Fragments. The dynamic nature of Fragments lies in the fact that you can substitute one Fragment for another whenever you want and you can reuse Fragments even in different Activities, but each Fragment has a mostly pre-defined layout, which is why you want to use XML.

When they say dynamic in the tutorial, they don't mean only in code. They mean in design as well. For example, have a look at this figure from the tutorial:

[image]

For a tablet you would want to use two fragments in the same screen, because there is more "real estate". For a smartphone, it'll be too crowded to put the two fragments next to each other, so you would use only a single fragment at each time, and navigate to the other fragment in response to the user's interaction  with the UI. So you build your Fragments with their life cycle, look-and-feel and logic only once, and then you can use them in many different ways depending on your current context (wider screen, taller screen, ...).

Comment: I believe OP was interested in using the <fragment> tag not inflating layout in fragment's onCreateView.

Comment: Hi Eugen. Best to create a directory for different screen sizes and types (see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and arrange your fragments according to the different screen types and orientation. You still use <fragment> in XML instead of replacing them in Java code. In code, you can check current screen size, density and orientation and only decide if an action should be taken (when item in A is clicked, if device is not tablet [only one fragment is displayed] start Activity that displays fragment B / change fragment A to fragment B ...).

Comment: Also, using XML is faster than running Java code and is neater (you don't need to use FragmentManager with its commit() / commitAllowStateLoss()).

Comment: @logcat Thank you so much for the detailed response! Really cleared up a lot of my confusion :)